# In Rule Chain, how to aggregate data and calculate the average base on Time?

Tags: thingsboard

[My_rule_chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSkA8.png)

Hi

Im trying to create a Lever Meter Dashboard. I already getting the reading of the level in gallons, i calculate the percentage and calculate the consumption. I need to calculate the average consumption in a hour. But i cant find the right node to do it.

PS. Im new in Thingsboard

[Aggregate stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXi4w.png)[Originator Telemetry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2G6b.png)

I try to use the Aggregate stream node and calculate the average in 1 hour. And also use a originator telemetry node to store the last data in an hour and calculate the average. But in both cases the node pass out data every 10 minute (Timer of the sensor).

I already calculate the consumption. I want a way to aggregate that consumption for 1 hour and calculate the average and pass the average consumption in 1 hour.

Comment: Can you please post the `Consumption` and `avgHourlyGallons` timeseries data?
Also please post your desired shape of data-sample. 
I noticed that in your `aggregate stream` node is that the `Interval persistence policy` as *On each message*, which effectively will trigger persistence of aggregated data every time a message is received. 

Please confirm if it is right to assume that your entity's timeseries publish interval is 10 minutes. 

Also please confirm whether the `Consumption` data is a *delta* one or *cumulative*.